# Create a SQL query to retrieve the most recent record by user

Tags: sql

I am trying to have this query return only the most recent transaction record for only specific users,  currently I am using this query however it is muddled with extra information that I do not need.

```
SELECT TOP 30 
    USER_NAME, 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(20), ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME, 20) AS DATE_TIME, 
    WORK_TYPE, Location, ITEM, Quantity 
FROM 
    TRANSACTION_HISTORY 
WHERE 
    USER_NAME in ('a_user','b_user','c_user','d_user','e_user')
ORDER BY 
    activity_date_time DESC
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can change top 30 to top 1 if you only want one record, but what is the extra information that you do not need?

Comment: Which rdbms are you on?

Comment: What is the structure of the Transaction_history table? In particular what is the primary key?

Comment: just noticed that you convert to nvarchar and then name the column DATE_TIME? Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the most recent activity for each user (Assuming ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME is an actual Datetime field and not a varchar field)

```
SELECT 
    USER_NAME, 
    max(ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME) as  ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME
FROM 
    TRANSACTION_HISTORY 
WHERE 
    USER_NAME in ('a_user','b_user','c_user','d_user','e_user')
GROUP BY user_name
```

If you would have users with multiples of the same datetime (for instnce if you are not actually storing time), then you need to use rownumber to get one.

If you need other columns from the table as well then use the above query as a derived table:

```
SELECT <list the columns you need from theTRANSACTION_HISTORY table >
FROM TRANSACTION_HISTORY th
JOIN (
SELECT 
    USER_NAME, 
    max(ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME) as  ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME
FROM 
    TRANSACTION_HISTORY 
WHERE 
    USER_NAME in ('a_user','b_user','c_user','d_user','e_user')
GROUP BY user_name
) a  On th.USER_NAME = a.USER_NAME  and th. ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME = a. ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the user wants to return the latest transaction for each user in the `IN()` clause.

Had `users` been a different table I would have suggested a `JOIN/CROSS APPLY` on the most recent record in the `TRANSACTION_HISTORY` table. But as they are in the same table, how about a `UNION`?

```
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM TRANSACTION_HISTORY
WHERE USER_NAME = 'a_user'
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM TRANSACTION_HISTORY
WHERE USER_NAME = 'b_user'
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM TRANSACTION_HISTORY
WHERE USER_NAME = 'c_user'
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM TRANSACTION_HISTORY
WHERE USER_NAME = 'd_user'
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM TRANSACTION_HISTORY
WHERE USER_NAME = 'e_user'
ORDER BY ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME DESC
```

The `ORDER BY` here will apply to the entire query, as each individual `UNION` can't be ordered.

Comment: I'd still use cross apply but just do a psuedo user table via `select user_name = 'a_user' union select 'b_user' union select...`

Comment: Nice - didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming mssql 2005+, you can use row_number to partition by user and order by activity_date. Then you select only the user's first row...

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        USER_NAME, 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(20), ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME, 20) AS DATE_TIME, 
        WORK_TYPE, Location, ITEM, Quantity,
        RN = row_number() over(paritition by USER_NAME order by activity_date_time DESC)
    FROM 
        TRANSACTION_HISTORY 
    WHERE 
        USER_NAME in ('a_user','b_user','c_user','d_user','e_user')
) t
WHERE
    t.RN = 1 --only want the top history per user
```

If the table is really large, might be better to use apply instead as it looks like you only need to do it for a small number of users at a time...

```
 SELECT 
        TTH.* 
    FROM 
        USER U 
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1
                USER_NAME, 
                CONVERT(nvarchar(20), ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME, 20) AS DATE_TIME, 
                WORK_TYPE, Location, ITEM, Quantity
            FROM 
                TRANSACTION_HISTORY TH
            WHERE
                TH.USER_NAME = U.USER_NAME
            ORDER BY
                activity_date_time DESC
        ) TTH
    WHERE 
        U.USER_NAME in ('a_user','b_user','c_user','d_user','e_user')
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use a CTE (Common Table Expression) if you're on SQL Server 2005 and newer (you aren't specific enough in that regard - other RDBMS also have the CTE and the windowing functions like `ROW_NUMBER` - those aren't SQL Server specific features).

With this CTE, you can partition your data by some criteria - i.e. your `User_Name` - and have SQL Server number all your rows starting at 1 for each of those "partitions", ordered by some other criteria (like the date, in your case).

So try something like this:

```
;WITH MostRecentPerUser AS
(
   SELECT 
       USER_NAME, 
       CONVERT(nvarchar(20), ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME, 20) AS DATE_TIME, 
       WORK_TYPE, Location, ITEM, Quantity,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USER_NAME ORDER BY CAST(ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME AS DATETIME) ) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM 
       dbo.Transaction_History
   WHERE
       USER_NAME in ('a_user', 'b_user', 'c_user', 'd_user', 'e_user')
)
SELECT 
   USER_NAME, 
   DATE_TIME, 
   WORK_TYPE, Location, ITEM, Quantity
FROM 
   MostRecentPerUser 
WHERE
   RowNum = 1
```

Here, I am selecting only the "first" entry for each "partition" (i.e. for each `User_Name`) - ordered by `Date_Time`.

Does that approach what you're looking for??

Three side notes:

- first of all, if you have a date - why isn't this stored as `DATETIME` or `DATE` ? It should be - seriously! Don't store dates as `NVARCHAR(20)` - never!
- I would try to avoid ALL UPPERCASE IDENTIFIERS - these make your code really hard to read and comprehend. We're way past the ALL UPPERCASE terminals by now - aren't we?
- Also: I would recommend trying to use more meaningful and expressive names than `DATE_TIME` - first of all, you're at risk of colliding with a SQL Server keyword like `DATETIME` or `DATE`, and secondly - you should strive to make your column names (and aliases) really express what they represent - a `SalesDate` or `ActivityDate` are much better than just `DATE_TIME`.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve all the fields of the record from the table `TRANSACTION_HISTORY` that has the most recent `activity_date_time`

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION_HISTORY ORDER BY activity_date_time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Change the `*` to the fields you want to retrieve.

Obviously, if you want to only retrieve a record where the `USER_NAME` column has a value from any of  `('a_user','b_user','c_user','d_user','e_user')`, add the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TRANSACTION_HISTORY 
WHERE USER_NAME in ('a_user','b_user','c_user','d_user','e_user')
ORDER BY activity_date_time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: what about the specific users?

Comment: _it is muddled with extra information_ I'm assuming that is part of the muddled info.

Comment: @ribot What do you mean? It just reduces the set of available rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT USER_NAME, convert(nvarchar(20),  
ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME, 20) as DATE_TIME, WORK_TYPE, 
Location, ITEM,Quantity 
FROM TRANSACTION_HISTORY WHERE USER_NAME in 
('a_user','b_user','c_user','d_user','e_user')
order by ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME desc LIMIT 1
```

Does this help?